# JAVASCRIPT equivalent of exit

Tags: jquery, exit, halt

Pretty simple question, but much to my surprise I could not find an answer on the internets.

In PHP we have exit; which will simply stops executing any further code when it reaches that line, assuming there are no errors.

Does jQuery (JAVASCRIPT for all yous) have a similar built in function? This is to be used for debugging, not for production.

Thanks!

Comment: @Krishna You can't return from a top level code though, you must be inside a function.

Comment: `jQuery` is just a library.  I think you want to know if javascript has this ability.

Comment: You may not have found much of an answer because this is not a jQuery question. It's more about the fundamentals of JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on from where you want to exit.

Comment: `exit()` is used in PHP when say... the Database can not be reached... but at the UI layer... under what possible condition would you hit that you can't provide something more meaningful to the user vs. exit?

Comment: Since you're doing it purely for debugging, you'd be better off using breakpoints.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. Not understanding why someone wants to do something is grounds for a question or a suggestion, not a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.stop()` (vanilla JavaScript, not jQuery) would simulate the user clicking the Stop button on the browser, preventing the browser from downloading and rendering the current page.

Comment: Someone's gone crazy with the downvotes

Comment: This will do, thanks. as no one else seemed to understand what I was getting at. Just me or is this place turning into something... unproductive.

Comment: For the record (and I'm not trying to be rude... I'm genuinely curious) what are you hoping to accomplish? I would think that some error handling would be much more helpful in pointing out and resolving issues vs. just giving up and stop loading the page (with no indication of the error?)

Comment: This is a combination of error handling. More to the point, if it errors as I define, I want to witness the accumulated affect up to that precise instant and no further.

Answer (score -1):

First, a pet peeve:  there's no such language as jQuery.  That's just a library framework on top of JavaScript.  The question is presumably whether JavaScript has an `exit` function.

If you want to stop script execution, and you're in a debug environment, you have a few options, none of which are exit:

- You can pop up an alert.  This will stop execution, but doesn't let you do much.
- You can use the `debugger;` statement.  This may be what you want - just put it in a line, and if your console is open, it will bring up the debugger at that point.

The last alternative will work, but isn't pretty.  Simply throw an exception (or cause one of your own, e.g. `myNonExistantVariable.thereIsNoProperty.soExceptionWillHappen = 0;`